# Simple 2D representation of a 3D color array

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, computer-vision

I'd like to generate a 2d image to visualice a 3d array in python 3.5

I've found complex solutions like marching cubes.

But I need to see every voxel, instead of converting a 3d discrete image into a polygonal mesh.

So printing each slice with perspective is a valid solution.
I'm dealing with medical images which have been masked.  So there ara lots of transparent pixels with value 0.

The 3d scatterplots I've found aren't valid, since they represent voxels as figures.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Virilo

Comment: What are the dimensions of the 3D array? I don't understand what you mean by this: "The 3D scatterplots . . . represent voxels as figures." Have you seen any example images created using OpenGL that look similar to what you want?

Comment: how big is it? do you need them transparent? is it for an animation? are you asking for advice on the distribution and transparency of the cubes? If i was you i would code a super advanced on, which animates slices through the 3d voxel. and one that animates selections within it, i.e. of colors. and that can chante transparency. i would do it in JS in unity3d though which has easy access to cubes, colors, arrays, .net functions, spacial info